# linq query Unable to create a constant value collection within collection

Tags: linq, entity-framework

im trying to get the articles which are labled as publid (DisplayFor = false) or with required permission (DisplayFor = true; and article.groups contains the granted groups;) and (GroupId = Guid.Empty for every registered user):

```
List<Group> groups = new UserBiz().Groups(AchaAuth.CurrentUserId);
var result = from HeadsupArticle article in ctx.HeadsupArticles
                             where article.GroupId == item.GroupId &&
                                   article.Active &&
                                   (!article.DisplayFor || (article.DisplayFor && article.Groups.Any(g =>
                                    g.GroupId == Guid.Empty ||
                                    groups.Select(i => i.GroupId).Contains(g.GroupId)
                                   )))
                             select article;
```

the problem is

```
Unable to create a constant value of type 'Achasoft.AchaCms.Models.Group'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.
```

i need a proper linq query so i wouldnt need to select 1000s of records in order to get 10 records out of it

Comment: This has **nothing** to do with your LINQ query...

Comment: then can you enlighten me what should i do?

Comment: Doubleclick the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. This will remove the groups list from the LINQ query, but if your groupId is a Guid and a user can have multiple groups you will be sending a really big list of guids to the query.

```
List<Group> groups = new UserBiz().Groups(AchaAuth.CurrentUserId);
var groupsIds = groups.Select(i => i.GroupId).ToList();
var result = from HeadsupArticle article in ctx.HeadsupArticles
                             where article.GroupId == item.GroupId &&
                                   article.Active &&
                                   (!article.DisplayFor || (article.DisplayFor && article.Groups.Any(g =>
                                    g.GroupId == Guid.Empty ||
                                    groupsIds.Contains(g.GroupId)
                                   )))
                             select article;
```

When the groupIds section was included in the query. EF was trying to convert the Enumerable into the SQL Query and that is just not possible. By extracting and forcing the ToList() (The ToList is the important part) you are forcing EF to convert the list into a SQL query that would look like

```
 WHERE g.GroupId IN ('guid1', 'guid2', ... 'guidN')
```

Comment: thanks man you saved my day; i tried to mark as answer but it says it has to wait!!!!!!!! any ways can you tell me why that line should have come outside?

Comment: When you are dealing with LINQ to entities, you can't send non primitive values to a query. By extracting the groups basically ef will convert the groupIds into a WHERE g.GroupdId IN ('guid1', 'guid2', ..., 'guidN')